# In a foreach loop how do I find the average of the two columns to the left of the respective variable?

Tags: stata

In Stata: So far I have

```
foreach i of varlist v8 - v23 {
     gen v_`i' = (`i'[_n-2]*`i'[_n-3] * `i'[_n-4])/3
}
```

But this isn't doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That averages previous observations, not previous variables.

Your question title is about the average of two columns (meaning variables). Your code looks like an attempt to code the average of three variables. I will run with the second.

Your variables run 8 to 23; so the first average is for position 11 as the average of 8, 9, 10.

```
forval j = 11/23 {
    local 3 = `j' - 3 
    local 2 = `j' - 2 
    local 1 = `j' - 1 
    generate v_`j' = (v`3' + v`2' + v`1') / 3 
}
```

That could be squeezed into fewer lines, but it seems more important to show some structure clearly.

If 8 to 23 represent different times, and in many other situations too, you would be better off after a `reshape long`.